# Codeigniter ERROR --> 404 Page Not Found --> public

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, message

I have this log_message error and I don't know why?

```
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> Total execution time: 0.0583
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> Router Class Initialized
**ERROR - 2016-10-26 19:06:38 --> 404 Page Not Found --> public**
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:39 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:39 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-10-26 19:06:39 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
```

And the controller

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends Admin_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load user model
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/layouts/users_view');
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer');
    }

    public function get_users(){

        echo  $this->user_model->get_users();

    }

}
```

get_users function get data for Datatables with Datatables librery.
Called from view with ajax.

Comment: Can you post you some code, especially controller

Comment: The usual reason for this is not using an upper-case first letter in the file name. So, class Users' file name should be **U**sers.php

Comment: The controller name is Users.php but when i call another Controller i have the same error.

Comment: check ajax request url in your browser console you might be made some spelling mistake in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your controller extends the Admin_Controller if all i can see is only basic Codeigniter methods, why not have it extend the main **CI_Controller**?

Maybe this is your problem, in order to use a controller in Codeigniter, it must extend the CI_Controller in order to inherit all of its methods ($this) unless you want to make a library or a helper, they don't need to extend the CI_Controller.

- Make sure your page is respecting these rules :  Class name and the
  controller file name **Must** be the same, ex : class : **User**, controller
  file : **User.php**
- Make sure your roues aren't overriding your controller with a
  nonexistent link.
- Make sure your views are in the right path, unless it might pop
  up a 404 error.

Comment: I call a .css file from public assets, and the link is wrong :)

Comment: to call your css file from the public assets, use the following syntax :

Comment: <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
And make sure that your config.php has the right base_url() address